# React.NET - ReactScriptLoadException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reactjs.net

I keep getting the following error within my ASP.NET MVC 5 solution with React.NET 
***Error while loading "~/Scripts/jsx/components/HomeComp.jsx": TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'createClass'
  at Global code (Script Document:6:1)
Line: 6
Column:1***
 when trying to server side render a react component return within my MVC view. I have bundled all the necessary scripts and tried including the following within my web configs   along with adding the following refs to my layout view

```
@using React.Web.Mvc;
@using System.Web.Optimization;
@using System.Web.Optimization.React;
```

but I keep getting the same error, I'm guessing its got to do with the way I have setup my solution, any help will be much appreciated. I have shared the project via my google drive for a better understanding.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LCIlQRZNGckYKWbT4fwp1XDrW0lHZ8t9?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to use the legacy `React.createClass` syntax. This is no longer supported by React out-of-the-box. Try using the newer syntax with `React.Component` instead. See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html for example.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for a great tutorial on https://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial.html. I got the samme error as above after following your guide. Is there a new version to the tutorial that includes waht you are saying here?

Comment: I haven't had time to update the tutorial :( Maybe someone will submit a pull request to update it, otherwise I can do it if/when I get some free time.